# Javascript setInterval runs after setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

Idea - i want to show an alert to the user when a request is put through - The alert works fine and shows the information but the sound part isn't working correct.

The sound which i want to repeat continually until the user acknowledges the alert only plays after the message has been accepted

Could someone explain why this is happening and help with a solution?

```js
function ShowAlert(alert) {
    if (alert) {
        // A nomination or renomination has been entered so alert the user
        
        let intervalId = setInterval(function() {
            console.log('playing sound')
            sound = document.getElementById("nominationAlertSound");
            sound.play();
        }, 3000);
        
        
        //Show alert after page has loaded 
        setTimeout(function() {
            var ack = false;
            while (!ack) {
                // Nomination or renomination has not been acknowledged yet
                var message = alert.message + "\n\nSelect OK to acknowledge this alert and continue.";
                ack = confirm(message);
            }
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            AcknowledgeAlert();
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `confirm` or `alert` or `prompt` - these block the UI thread.

Comment: That while loop is going to cause problems.

Comment: There **has** to be a good dupetarget for this...

Comment: There's only one main UI thread on browsers. Your `while` loop and `confirm` call will prevent that thread from doing anything else -- such as starting a sound playing.

Comment: Thanks guys, removing the while and confirm did the trick! will just need to design a nice wee pop up manually